# Cannot open database requested by the login in other computers except for mine

Tags: c#, sql

Hi I created a C# winforms application, I added a connection with my database which I created in Sql Server 2008 Express in Management Studio. I published the project and everything seems to be working fine in my computer, but when i ran the setup in another computer, the program had stopped working and showed this message error.
I want the application to run in any computer.

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: geography.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03: 525520ed
  Problem Signature 04: System.Data
  Problem Signature 05: 4.0.30319.17929
  Problem Signature 06: 4ffa5c76
  Problem Signature 07: 2592
  Problem Signature 08: 27
  Problem Signature 09: System.Data.SqlClient.Sql
  OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1032
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

My connection string is `Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=geografia;Integrated Security=True`

I changed it to Data Source=**(local)**\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=geografia;Integrated Security=True but still the same result.

Then i tried to catch the error with a try catch block in the first database connection and when i ran the program it showed me `cannot open database "geografia" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'pcname-PC\username'.`

When I was publishing the application I included geography.pdb as data file (geography is the name of my project and I don't know if thatis for embedding the database)

I am new to programming and I don't know if I attached my database in the application.

I read some stuff but i am a bit confused. Is there any idea?

Comment: First thing to be aware of integrated security only works between multiple PCs if they are on a domain, because the windows users on PC2 have no Relation to the Windows users on PC1.

Comment: Try the `hostname` of your instead of `localhost`, `hostname\sqlexpress`

Comment: I want it to run in any computer, so what would be the appropriate hostname?

Comment: As far as I know .pdb is file containing debug symbols. You need a real database, if you're going to distribute database file with your application, try SQL Compact, it has .sdf files

Answer (score 0):

change the connection string with proper server name

```
Data Source=<serrvername>\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=geografia;Integrated Security=True
```

If you are using (local) or DOT(.) It means that it has to connect to computer in which application is running. In this case if you dont have sql server or database installed on different computer it will throw this error.

Comment: I want it to run in any computer, so what would be the appropriate servername?

Comment: if you want to have a common sql server for all installations, you should give the servername of the sql server. if you want have separate sql server for each installation , you can proceed with dor

Comment: thank you for your replies, but I haven't understood yet, I think I won't know which sql server is installed on the computer the application to be installed, that's why i put on prerequisites maybe sql server 2008. Can you give me more information about dor?

Comment: Sorry it is not dor its .(DOT) . Means connect to sql server installed in local machine

Comment: in the second computer, sql server is installed, so the database is not installed. do you know a way so that database can be installed during the setup?

Comment: THat is the different process to be followed, its better to give script and install manually unless if you a product

Answer (score 0):

Since your application is working fine on your computer when having dot(.), you can use servername as your machine name.

Also instead of using Integrated security, try using username and password of Sql Server.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is how you attach to your database

- If your database is attached with window authentication this will from
  your machine only unless you are on a domain
- If your attached database with SQL server authentication this will from any computer.

Observations : attach to your database with SQL server not with database SQL server file. If you choose database file, you can't connect to machine with your database SQL server